# UEFI Secure Boot:- bad shim signature

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, secure-boot, pxe

Before proceeding I don't want to disable the Secure Boot option. I need a solution, not a workaround.

I have a humble setup using dnsmasq and the dnsmasq built-in tftp to give me a PXE server. I am trying to boot Ubuntu 22.04.

Setup:

I followed the [official Ubuntu tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/netboot-amd64).

Initially I had problem with bootx64.efi as the NUC reported a boot violation, but the trick was to basically use the bootx64.efi.dualsigned to create the bootx64.efi. This is the result of sbverify on bootx64.

[image: have a look here]

This solved the problem of boot policy violation and the pxe boot process successfully starts grub. I don't know how as the sbverify fails on this file.

[image: have a look here]

After I select from grub which ISO to run this is the error message I get

[image: have a look here]

I don't know if this is the problem with grub or the actual signature of vmlinuz.

[image: have a look here]

Without turning off Secure Boot how do I sign the kernel image with the correct and update signature or the grubx64.efi to make this work? Is there a way to do this with sbattach command (don't I need the actual public certificate for that) where can I find this certificate?

Comment: You don't mention which Ubuntu 22.04 image you're using, due to security issues which led to a now *revoked* key; you may need to use the Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS image (which includes the newer key).  Is that what you used? or did you use an older ISO (*with revoked keys*)

Comment: So @guiverc I used ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS for this. I am going to give this a try using the Ubuntu 22.04.3. Can you share me some article as to why these keys were revoked ?. I want to see if there is a way to secure boot older OS as it is a business need, I can't just throw hands up. Is there no way to sign older kernel with updated keys/signature ?. Why does by grub fail verification even when the latest signature is included ?.

Comment: @guiverc, just tested with ubuntu 22.04.3 kernel and it works but the problem is why does it work ?. The output of sbverify shows the verification failed for grubx64 and vmlinuz. The only successful verification happens on bootx64 file. am I using correct methos to verify  signatures?. The only think common in all the files I can see is the signature 2022 v1. Is there a way to add this 2022 v1 signature to the vmlinuz of the OS 22.04.1 so that I can boot into this with secure boot enabled ?.

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sbat-revocations-boot-process/34996

Comment: @guiverc, I really appreciate you sharing this article as it explains why this is not working but this still does not really answer my questions. The only way I can think of booting the previous kernels (with revoked keys) is to simply use MOK to register my own keys into firmware of each machine and sign the kernels with it too to make it boot but caveat is I accept the risks associated with that release. I am newbie so excuse what I am going to ask next :- Is it not possible to have the new signatures public part to sign the old kernels with (which defeats the purpose of secure boot??)

Comment: @guiverc also why would the setup work with 22.04.3 when the sbverify on grubx64.efi and vmlinuz fail?

Comment: I don't have the technical knowledge you seek sorry; I'm with *Ubuntu News* thus see announcements/CVEs/releases etc, I'm also involved with other teams but most is well out of my skill-set (such as SHIMs). The prior link I gave maybe related more to change with 22.04.2, but I recall the 22.04.3 SHIM changing impacting other release(s) in the weeks earlier, but given 22.04.3 was so close it was done then for *jammy*. I don't need to know technical details of it, and what I read I tend to retain only a few days as I have no need to retain it and I move to next thing (*mantic beta* currently)

Answer (score 1):

- The answer to your question is in the output of the various `sbverify --list` commands you ran.
- As listed in the output of the command for `vmlinuz`, it is signed using `Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2017)`
- The grub loader is signed using the `Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2022 v1)`
- Sometime in 2022, Canonical started using `Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2022)` to sign keys and revoked the `Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2017)` key. This ended up being added to the DBX  (`Secure Boot Forbidden Signature Database`) (which is part of the secure-boot storage in BIOS, and updated regularly).
- To fix, you just need to update the kernel (and matching initrd) being served via tftp to one signed using `Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2022)`.