# Migrating Ubuntu-20.04 boot disk from old laptop to new laptop with secure-boot enabled

Tags: secure-boot

I have an laptop running 20.04 (no `secure-boot`, title it `old`). I wanted to move the boot disk to a new laptop (titled `new`) which has secure-boot enabled. I do **not** want to disable `secure boot` on `new`, because I have windows installed on `new`  with requirements to keep `secure boot` enabled.

To test whether this was possible for `new`, I plugged my original install live-media (the `xubuntu 18.04` live boot image from *2019* on USB, used to install `old`), and tried to boot `new` off it. This succeeded perfectly.

Next I took the boot disk from `old`, plugged it into `new`, selected the disk as boot media, and got to the grub console. This is where I got stuck with the following error message:

```
Loading Linux 5.4.0-70-generic ...
error: bad shim signature.
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue...
```

I booted `old` to compare the kernel on the boot media vs the kernel on disk:

```
samveen@samveen-X230:~$ sudo sbverify --list /media/temp/casper/vmlinuz 
signature 1
image signature issuers:
 - /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/L=Douglas/O=Canonical Ltd./CN=Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
image signature certificates:
 - subject: /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/O=Canonical Ltd./OU=Secure Boot/CN=Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing
   issuer:  /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/L=Douglas/O=Canonical Ltd./CN=Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
```

```
samveen@samveen-X230:/media/temp/casper$ sudo sbverify --list /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-70-generic 
signature 1
image signature issuers:
 - /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/L=Douglas/O=Canonical Ltd./CN=Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
image signature certificates:
 - subject: /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/O=Canonical Ltd./OU=Secure Boot/CN=Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2017)
   issuer:  /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/L=Douglas/O=Canonical Ltd./CN=Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
```

Both are signed and valid, so I checked on the bootloader chain (shim and grub):

```
samveen@samveen-X230:~$ sudo sbverify --list /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
warning: data remaining[834920 vs 960472]: gaps between PE/COFF sections?
signature 1
image signature issuers:
 - /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011
image signature certificates:
 - subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Windows UEFI Driver Publisher
   issuer:  /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011
 - subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011
   issuer:  /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation Third Party Marketplace Root
samveen@samveen-X230:~$ sudo sbverify --list /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
signature 1
image signature issuers:
 - /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/L=Douglas/O=Canonical Ltd./CN=Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
image signature certificates:
 - subject: /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/O=Canonical Ltd./OU=Secure Boot/CN=Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2022 v1)
   issuer:  /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/L=Douglas/O=Canonical Ltd./CN=Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
samveen@samveen-X230:~$ sudo sbverify --list /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
warning: data remaining[742792 vs 860824]: gaps between PE/COFF sections?
signature 1
image signature issuers:
 - /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/L=Douglas/O=Canonical Ltd./CN=Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
image signature certificates:
 - subject: /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/O=Canonical Ltd./OU=Secure Boot/CN=Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2022 v1)
   issuer:  /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/L=Douglas/O=Canonical Ltd./CN=Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
```

That's all valid, with the `Canonical Ltd. Master CA` being able to validate everything.

What am I missing here which is causing the failure to boot?

Comment: Root cause is https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sbat-revocations-boot-process/34996 . This was previously discussed at https://askubuntu.com/q/1429678/1004020 but I prefer your answer over that one because secure boot shouldn't be disabled

Comment: If this question gains traction, I might flag https://askubuntu.com/q/1503878/1004020 https://askubuntu.com/q/1495766/1004020 https://askubuntu.com/q/1494338/1004020 https://askubuntu.com/q/1486219/1004020 https://askubuntu.com/q/1501752/1004020 as duplicates and point them to this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating a lot more, I found that the certificate used to sign the kernel I was booting was in the  Secure Boot Forbidden Signature Database (`dbx`) (`Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2017)`).

To fix the issue, I had to update to the latest `image-generic` kernel which was `linux-image-5.4.0-172-generic` (signed by latest CA) instead of the outdated `linux-image-5.4.0-70-generic` that I was using.

A couple of other issues with missing drivers were fixed by replacing the `image-generic` kernel series with the Hardware Enablement kernel series `linux-generic-hwe-20.04`. More details at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

DKMS modules signing was already implemented, even on `old`(even though it was unused) , with the machine owner key already created when I first installed the OS (xubuntu 18.04 on `old`, in 2019). I just needed to enroll my MOK into the Shim by following the process as documented in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot . *Edit: I needed this only to load upstream VirtualBox kernel modules built by DKMS, else this step wasn't required.*

***Side note**: I had installed Xubuntu `18.04` on `old` in 2019, and then went through the dist-upgrade process to `20.04` in early 2021. The secure boot setup as created at install was valid on `new` in 2024 (5 years after install) even after dist-upgrade to `20.04`. That's quite some planning for future-proofing by Ubuntu. Even though I am unhappy with how `22.04` is structured and am planning on shifting to upstream Debian eventually, `20.04` with `hwe` kernel series is a good bet for even the recent laptops.*

Comment: New install media was created; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ before the keys were revoked. If all security fixes had been applied (*on installed systems, prior to this ISO release too*), you should have had new keys installed already.

Comment: @guiverc Before or after, *I have **no keys installed***. I used the Xubuntu 18.04 boot media created in 2019. The private key used to sign the kernel image in that boot media was valid, allowing that kernel to boot. However, the signing key used to sign the older boot media kernel was different than the one uses for the 5.4.0-70 generic kernel for 20.04(the old 20.04 signing key fingerprint was added to the blacklist). That aside, **you are right** that I missed the updates that used the new signing key, which is why the first boot failed.

Comment: My mention of Keys refers to MOK/keys on the OS itself, required to boot with uEFI *secure boot*. The release link I provided mentions "*Unlike previous point releases, 20.04.6 is a refresh of the amd64 installer media after recent key revocations, re-enabling their usage on Secure Boot enabled systems*", those keys being *disabled* on INSTALLED systems as well as all install media; if updates were fully applied, the revoked keys would have been replaced prior the revocation [date].

Comment: FYI:  All Xubuntu 18.04 media uses now *revoked* keys, and can only be used with with secure boot disabled; as no *flavor* of 18.04 was still *supported* when new 18.04 media was created (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/).. again similar message "*Unlike previous point releases, 18.04.6 is a refresh of the amd64 and arm64 installer media after the key revocation related to the BootHole vulnerability, re-enabling their usage on Secure Boot enabled systems. More detailed information can be found here..*"  Keys on Xubuntu media were valid at time of creation

Comment: @guiverc DBX is up to date on `new` (newly bought, with all Win11 updates). The Xubuntu 18.04 media still booted up fine (`README.diskdefines` says `Xubuntu 18.04.2 LTS "Bionic Beaver" - Release amd64`), so older media was signed different. The MOK is not required to boot, per se. It'sare only required to tack local modifications onto the secure boot chain of validations, like `DKMS` modules or _locally built kernels_. Upstream kernels are signed by the the key embedded in the Ubuntu `shim`, which, in turn, is signed by the root CA of the secure boot system, i.e. the `Microsoft UEFI CA 2011`.